# Displaying hdf5 file at correct location?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, satellite, solar-radiation, hdf5

I have downloaded the INSAT-K1 VHR INSOLATION PRODUCT (https://mosdac.gov.in/catalog/doi/36). This is satellite data in hdf5 format. When I display the raster in either ArcGIS or QGIS it appears at the wrong geographic position (image attached).

[image]

The hdf5 files are GCS_WGS_1984, Datum: D_WGS1984. I have tried creating a mosaic dataset (ArcCatalog) with these details before adding the data but this has not helped. (I’m using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop).
I would like to correctly geolocate the raster in order to extract values at point locations from it.

[image]

Comment: According to the [INSAT-3D Products Catalog](http://satellite.imd.gov.in/dynamic/INSAT3D_Catalog.pdf), the outputs from this weather satellite have this domain: 40 S to 40 N, 30 E to 120 E. The standard WGS84 coordinate system has an extent of -180.00, -90.00, 180.00, 90.00. So...there's a conflict there, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Seems to be a projection issue though.

Comment: @csk,  40 S to 40 N, 30 E to 120 E is  30, -40, 120, 40 so within WGS84 extent. The issue is that the GIS is not picking up the georeferencing at all, the data origin is being placed at 0,0 with pixel size = 1.

Comment: What's different between the two images? Is one image in QGIS, and the other in Arc?

Comment: Yes, the top image is in ArcGIS, the lower one is in QGIS

Answer (score 1):

I received this response after forwarding my Stack Exchange question to MOSDAC:

> Since these products are in h5, there are some issues in opening them
>   directly in GIS. However, I would suggest you  that these datsets can
>   be visualised and analysed using IDV (Integrated Data viewer -
>   freeware) from unidata.

I will experiment with the suggested software and test whether I can either carry out the analysis I need directly or convert the hdf5 into a format which GIS can georeference.